# Live edit Javascript in Chrome

Tags: haskell, yesod

Since Yesod embeds Javascript on to the page, Chrome is unable to edit the Javascript live to diagnose issues that I can't reproduce locally. Is there a way to edit the javascript on a running service in Yesod?

Chrome has the ability to edit live javascript as long as the script is coming from a standalone .js file, however Yesod embeds the js in to the page instead.

Comment: Do you mean it embeds along with the html code inside `<script>` tags ? Note that you have the option to embed it as a separate javascript file.

Comment: Yep `<script>` tags - they're snippets included in a widget.

Comment: Then why don't you make Yesod to include your script as a separate javascript file ? Then you can live edit it in Chrome.